# Getting SQL job status with Node.js call

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm starting a SQL job with Node.js, here is my current Node.js code:

```
router.post('/StartJob', (req, res, next) => {

    const jobName = req.body.jobName; 

    var request4 = new sql.Request();    

    request4.query('EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N' + "'" + jobName + "';", function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).json({
                Error: err
            });
        }
        else {
            res.status(201).json({
                success: "Success"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I get a immediate success response when I call the job. But the job has three steps, and it usually takes about 30 seconds to complete. How can I get a response when the job has completed rather than the immediate success response when it is successfully started?

Comment: you can try poling them in regular interval to check the status.